# Фиксация фона при создании сайта

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как фиксировать фон в HTML коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Фиксированный фон на сайте](http://www.sd-company.su/article/html_css/background#sds_1)

Answer (score 0):

таблице стилей там где свойства фона добавляем 
    background-attachment:fixed;

Answer (score 0):

body{
background:url(/images/bg-image.gif) fixed;
}